# Facing issue while running minibuke on alpine:3.6/3.7

Tags: minikube

I am able to build the minikube on alpine but facing issue while starting it.

Failed to start the minikube 
/src/k8s.io/minikube # ./out/minikube-linux-amd64 start --vm-driver=none

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
E0712 16:31:44.365304   12423 start.go:258] Error updating cluster:  starting kubelet: running command:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload &&
sudo systemctl enable kubelet &&
sudo systemctl start kubelet
: exit status 1
================================================================================
An error has occurred. Would you like to opt in to sending anonymized crash
information to minikube to help prevent future errors?
To opt out of these messages, run the command:
        minikube config set WantReportErrorPrompt false
================================================================================
Please enter your response [Y/n]:
```

The logs of minikube :

/src/k8s.io/minikube # ./out/minikube-linux-amd64 logs

```
2018/07/12 16:35:48 Error getting machine logs: getting cluster logs: running command: sudo journalctl  -u kubelet
 output: sudo: journalctl: command not found
: running command: sudo journalctl  -u kubelet
.: exit status 1
================================================================================
An error has occurred. Would you like to opt in to sending anonymized crash
information to minikube to help prevent future errors?
To opt out of these messages, run the command:
        minikube config set WantReportErrorPrompt false
================================================================================
Please enter your response [Y/n]:
```

Any idea on how to start minikube on alpine?

Answer (score 0):

Minikube was developed to start in the environment with systemd. You can try to use the official image of Ubuntu or other distribution of Linux with systemd inside. For using Minikube inside the Alpine, you may take [this](https://github.com/moonswitch/minikube-alpine) or [this](https://github.com/whindes/alpine-minikube) as an example for you.

Comment: I think these examples are for older version of minikube, where the minikube uses localkube not kubeadm.

Comment: [rss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7854779/rss) 
kubeadm use the systemctl so you have 2 ways to resolve your problem:
1 install systemD to alpine
2 use image with preinstalled systemD

Comment: alpine has openrc rather than systemd. I am not sure about having systemd in alpine.

Comment: For your specific requirements use proper distribution of linux for example for this you could use Ubuntu in container.